# What is the meaning of the `|` symbol in the shell?

Tags: command-line, bash, process

What does the `|` symbol mean in `sudo ps -ef | grep processname` command?

Also can anyone please explain this command? I have used this command only for getting the PID and killing that process, but I also saw `sudo ps -ef | grep processname | grep -v grep` and I am under the impression that `-v grep` is like killing the previous generated PID for `grep`. If that's so how does it work?

Comment: You don't need `sudo` to run `ps -ef`. Also a common trick to avoid the third command is enclosing a character of the process' name in square brackets: `ps -ef | grep [p]rocessname`

Comment: oh cool kos its working, but i am running this command inside shell script, it also dispalying pid of shell script file if i run it like `./filename processName`

Comment: @kos That command needs quotes to work reliably: `ps -ef | grep '[p]rocessname'`

Comment: @kasperd I don't see why it would. Can you point that out?

Comment: If you're talking about the general case yes, if the pattern contains whitespace or characters that are going to be interpreted by the shell quoting is mandatory.

Comment: @kos If you write `grep [p]rocessname`, you are telling the shell to look for a file in the current directory with the name `processname` and substitute the pattern with the name of that file. If no file named `processname` exists, the shell may pass the pattern literally to grep. But that depends on your settings. So your version will break if a file named `processname` exists or if any of the following shell options has been enabled `failglob`, `nullglob`, `nocaseglob`.

Comment: @kasperd I misread your last comment, yes, you are correct about everything. I didn't consider that.

Comment: I can't believe this isn't a duplicate.

Comment: pipe. It means pipe.

Comment: ```|``` is covered in [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/23408)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
ps -ef | grep processname
```

It first runs `sudo ps -ef` and passes the output to the second command.

The second command filters all lines that contain word "processname".

`ps -ef | grep processname | grep -v grep` lists all lines containing `processname` and not containing `grep`.

According to `man grep`

```
-v, --invert-match
              Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v
              is specified by POSIX.)
```

According to `man ps`

```
ps displays information about a selection of the active processes.

-e     Select all processes.  Identical to -A.

-f     Do full-format listing. This option can be combined with many
          other UNIX-style options to add additional columns.  It also
          causes the command arguments to be printed.  When used with -L,
          the NLWP (number of threads) and LWP (thread ID) columns will be
          added.  See the c option, the format keyword args, and the
          format keyword comm.
```

You can combine parameters `-ef` means same as `-e -f`.

Actually `ps -ef | grep processname` list all occurrences of the process called `processname`.

Comment: thanks for explanation, what does `ps -ef` does exactly??

Comment: i think when we run `| grep processName` in terminal we also get output of grep which itself is a process so -v kills this output

Comment: You are correct.

Answer (score 35):

It's called `pipe`. It gives the output of the first command as the input to the second command.

In your case it means:
The result of `sudo ps -ef` is fed as the input of `grep processname`

`sudo ps -ef`:
This lists all the processes running. Type `man ps` in the termial for more.

`grep processname`
So, this list of processes is fed into grep which just searches for the program defined by `programname`.

#### Example

Typing `sudo ps -ef | grep firefox` in my terminal returns:

```
parto     6501  3081 30 09:12 ?        01:52:11 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
parto     8295  3081  4 15:14 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unity-scopes/scope-runner-dbus.py -s web/firefoxbookmarks.scope
parto     8360  8139  0 15:14 pts/24   00:00:00 grep --color=auto firefox
```

Comment: ok, what -v grep, what does it do.

Comment: good explanation but  i need some help on how `-v grep ` functions..

Comment: Oh, I see why `grep -v` is used. To filter out the last line.

Comment: @Aamir See my answer. `grep -v` filters OUT lines containing pattern.

Comment: You could also add that you can use multiple pipes. E.g. echo "foobar" | grep foo  | grep bar

Answer (score 6):

Im gonna try and answer this with a straight-forward practial answer:

The pipe `|` lets you do awesome stuff in the shell! It's the one single operator that i consider the most usefull and mighty.

how about counting files in a directory? simple:

`ls | wc -l` ..redirect the output of `ls` to `wc` wit parameter `-l` for lines

or counting of lines in a file?

```
cat someFile | wc -l
```

what if i want to search for something? 'grep' can search for occurences of strings:

```
cat someFile | grep aRandomStringYouWantToSearchFor
```

you just redirect the output of the command left of the Pipe to the command right of the pipe.

one more level: how often does something occure in a file?

```
cat someFile | grep aRandomStringYouWantToSearchFor | wc -l
```

you can use the | for nearly everything :)

```
fortune | cowsay
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, pipes are fun, +1, but please change the examples: [UUOC](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat).

Comment: Like: `grep -c "aRandomStringYouWantToSearchFor" "someFile"` ;-)

Comment: ofc. but for the purpose of simplicity ...the questionowner doesn't seem to be deeper in grep, e.g :)

Comment: Frankly a lot of your examples do not need pipes. Have you heard of demoggification? You are using cat and pipe when many of the commands will take the files as parameters directly:

    eg

cat someFile | grep aRandomStringYouWantToSearchFor

should be
    
    grep aRandomStringYouWantToSearchFor someFile

Comment: guys.. i know. if you read the comments, Captain, you would have read my response. 

The guy who asked the questions won't understand REAL applications of the pipe - he does not even know what grep is.

so shall i give him this example? 

`kill $(ps aux | awk '/someString/ { print $2}' | sed -n '1p')`

no, cause it would not serve the purpose at all.

Answer (score 4):

> I have used this command only for getting the PID and killing that process

Other answers have answered your main question already, but I'd like to address this as well;

In general *killing* a process is often an overkill and leaves resources allocated by a process around in a messy state, you can often just *terminate* it;

Beside this, just use `pkill` to kill / terminate a process. `pkill` supports specifying an exact process name or a regular expression:

```
pkill -x foo # Terminates process foo
pkill ^foo$ # Terminates process foo
pkill -9 -x foo # Kills process foo
pkill -9 ^foo$ # Kills process foo
```

Comment: Don't use `kill -9` unless you specifically know that no other signal will work.  See also http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#kill

Comment: @tripleee OP stated they want to *kill* the process though.

Comment: That's what `kill` does.  Specifying `-9` is an additional and most often disastrous extra option.

Comment: @tripleee I believe the confusion is arising because of the terminology; to me *kill* = SIGKILL, not SIGTERM.

Comment: For most people, I would expect "kill" to mean `kill`, plain and simple.  Any terminology aside, your answer should not advise people to use the `-9` option unless you put in a meaty caveat.

Comment: @tripleee To "kill" AFAIK means "killing", not "terminating". But beside this I just agree on the meaty caveat, so I added it to the answer.